# Is it possible to display a WPF Control in real-world, device-independent units? Milimeters, for example?

Tags: wpf, layout, screen-resolution

I am designing a product emulator in WPF. Our company sells a handheld electronic medical device, and we'd like to experiment with user interaction with a "virtual", skinned (sort of) GUI to represent buttons and leds.

Is there a way to "force" WPF to display stuff with its real-world dimension on the screen (by getting monitor dpi information, or something like this)?

As another example, suppose I can layout a plastic, standard-sized Credit Card using WPF controls (DockPanels, Labels, Canvases, etc.), could I consistently display it with the dimensions of a real credit card, across different desktops/laptops?

UPDATE:

I've found a clever way to design in "real milimeters" by using a `ViewBox` as the LayoutRoot of my window. Size of anything inside can be "designed in milimeters", and will be displayed in physical size PROVIDED that I can get the right pixel size for the ViewBox. And THAT remain a certain mistery:

- The relation between pixels and milimeters in my desktop seems to be 3.5 (where does this number come from?
- How could I implement a code-behind DataBound property or ValueConverter so that I could define a Zoom Level (via slider or hardcoded) to display a scaled (larger) version of the device if needed?

Comment: You'll have to read thru [this](http://www.wpflearningexperience.com/?p=41). I'm too lazy to read it myself. Otherwise I would post the answer to this question.

Comment: As a summary of the link, it says that WPF reads the dpi setting of the monitor, which is probably done by a service provided by Windows (and that could be cheated). Then my problem would be: "how to use this to get my desired size, and how to use it in my favor at design-time with Expression Blend"

Comment: @heltonbiker Thing is, you can pretty much bet on the DPI reported not matching the physical DPI unless you instruct the user to set Windows to match the manufacturer-provided information.

Comment: @millimoose Even considering the user to be educated in that sense, how could I get the APPLICATION to use that information and render thing with the right size? I wonder if code-behind + databound properties wouldn't be a way...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1831588/401828

Comment: @heltonbiker If I understand the article HighCore posted correctly, you just use 96 pixels = 1 inch. WPF coordinates are in device-independent-pixels. Basically, when you tell WPF to draw a "96-pixel" line, it will scale it according to the DPI automagically.

Answer (score 1):

I "sort of" solved the problem with the following strategy:

- My MainWindow has a ViweBox as LayoutRoot, and its Child is some container control (Border in this case) which represent the physical object;
- The ViewBox and everything inside it is defined as if WPF units were milimeters. So, if the product has a physical Width of 68mm, the Width property of the container control is 78. Everything else that is nested inside is treated as if WPF units were actual milimeters;
- The ViewBox has its Width and Height bounded to the Height and Width of the container control using a ValueConverter which multiplies by (96/25.4);
- Since everything inside a viewbox is scaled to fit (ViewBox.Stretch=Uniform), the value converter just resizes the viewbox, and the rest of layout redimensioning is achieved by the ViewBox embedded rendering transform (that I assume to be efficient enough).

My XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:PixelsToMilimeters x:Key="SizeConverter"/>       
</Window.Resources>

<Viewbox x:Name="LayoutRoot" Stretch="Uniform"
    Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=Case, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}"
    Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=Case, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}">
    <Border x:Name="Case" Width="108" Height="68">
    (...)
```

My code-behind:

```
    (...)
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value * (96/25.4);
    }
    (...)
```

Of course the "how can I be sure that DPI is actually 96?" is not solved, but that could be encapsulated, and the final result is close enough to the expected one, for my purposes.